# Why can't my function run for json in db.execute?

Tags: mysql, json, google-maps

I am using the `SELECT` function to pull out lat/long from an SQL Table, and am trying to convert it to JSON to be plugged into a Google Maps Markers Function.

```
db.execute("SELECT loc_LAT_poly, loc_LONG_poly 
            FROM markers 
            WHERE e_city=:e_city 
            AND e_state=:e_state 
            FOR JSON AUTO", 
            e_city=e_city, e_state=e_state)
```

With this code, I get a syntax error:

> RuntimeError: near "FOR": syntax error.

Where is my syntax error?
Thanks!

EDIT #1: This is being executed in a flask application (python) and then the JSON will be sent to a JavaScript function of Google Maps in an HTML page.

Comment: `FOR JSON AUTO` is not a recognized mysql syntax. It is unclear which programmation language you are using. Please update your question or add the proper tag so you can get help from the Stack Overflow communitty

Answer (score 1):

[FOR JSON AUTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) is an extension to SQL implemented by Microsoft SQL Server.

MySQL does not have this feature. It's proprietary to Microsoft.

You should understand which brand of RDBMS you are using, and understand that every brand of RDBMS has its own set of proprietary features.

You can use MySQL's [JSON_OBJECT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to format JSON field by field. See an example in the documentation.